$\dim W\leq \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$?

Let $W$ be a vector subspace of vector space $V$, $\sigma$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$. Prove that $\dim W\leq \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$.

Here $\sigma^{-1}(W)=\{v\in V; \sigma(v)\in W\}$.
At first, if $\sigma$ is not linear, $\sigma^{-1}(W)$ may be $\emptyset$. It is impossible. So I try to find a contourexample. But fails.
It seems that $W, \sigma^{-1}(W)$ has no relationship beteween their elements. So we consider $\sigma|_{\sigma^{-1}(W)}: \sigma^{-1}(W)\to W$. But the image of this map seems not to be $W$!
Oh..Any ideas?

A condition ensuring $\dim W \le \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$ is $W \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)$. Then the restriction $\sigma|_{\sigma^{-1}(W)}: \sigma^{-1}(W) \to W$ is surjective, so $\dim W \le \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$. Without $W \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)$, the inequality may not hold.

@RaynardBond But I could not give an counterexample

If $\sigma$ isn’t linear or $W$ isn’t a subspace, then $\dim W \le \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$ can fail. For example, let $V = \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma(x) = x^2$, and $W = (-\infty, 0)$ (not a subspace). Then $\sigma^{-1}(W) = \varnothing$, so $\dim W \le \dim \sigma^{-1}(W)$ fails. Linearity of $\sigma$ and $W$ being a subspace are essential.

Year, if $\sigma$ is linear$, $W$ is a subspace, can we prove it? If not, can we find an counterexample/

Let $K = \ker(\sigma)$, which lies in $\sigma^{-1}(W)$ since $\sigma(k) = 0 \in W$ for all $k \in K$. By rank–nullity (or a simple dimension argument on the restriction $\sigma|_{\sigma^{-1}(W)}$), we have
$$
\dim\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(W)\bigr) = \dim(K) + \dim\bigl(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))\bigr).\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Since $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W)) = W \cap \mathrm{Im}(\sigma) \subseteq W$, it follows that
$$
\dim\bigl(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))\bigr) \le \dim(W).
$$
Also, $\dim(K) \ge 0$. Hence,
$$
\dim\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(W)\bigr) \ge \dim(K) + \dim\bigl(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))\bigr) \ge \dim(W),\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
which proves $\dim(W) \le \dim\bigl(\sigma^{-1}(W)\bigr)$.

Edit by @tj_: Just let me finish up the approach @Raynard Bond:
From $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W)) = W \cap \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)$,
$$\dim \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))= \dim W + \dim \mathrm{Im}(\sigma) - \dim (W + \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)).$$
Hence by $(\ast)$ and $\dim V=\dim K + \dim \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)$:
$$\dim \bigl(\sigma^{-1}(W)\bigr) = \dim(K) + \dim W + \dim \mathrm{Im}(\sigma) - \dim (W + \mathrm{Im}(\sigma))
= \dim W + \dim V - \dim (W + \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)) \ge \dim W.$$

In $(\ast\ast)$ you used $\dim\bigl(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))\bigr) \ge \dim(W)$, but actually, you have the opposite relation $\dim\bigl(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(W))\bigr) \le \dim(W)$.
